Null Values posted for all but one column
I have the following DataFlow in ADF which parses a JSON file and uses the ID(s) of each object inside of an ExternalCall (Source). The JSON Properties inside the data returned from ExternalCall are translated (via the cachedMappings sink) into the appropriate SQL (Sink) Columns.
The main purpose of this Dataflow is to utilize the Drifted Schema capability since I will be passing different mappings and Parameters to make requests against different endpoints (from the same service) and to map the responses to the mappings assigned in cachedMappings. So I want to avoid any solutions which suggest hard coding or mapping any schemas directly to any one particular activity.

I am only testing with a small subset of the JSON Properties currently and when I check both the alterArray and the sqlSink DataPreview I can see the data values and columns as expected and the DataPreview Columns all match exactly (including capitalization) the same field names on the sqlSink Table.
ISSUE:
When I Debug (or even trigger) the DataFlow the ONLY column that posts is "shop_id". I have tried a number of different things including changing the column types in both ADF and Sql with no success.
AlterArray DataPreview - Correctly Showing 2 Rows will be Upserted

sqlSink DataPreview - Correctly Showing 2 Rows with 5 Columns all as Drifted

sqlSink Settings - Schema Drift Enabled. Table Key values are set with expression split($sinkKeys,',') from value 'Transaction_Id,Order_Id' which splits into existing Columns in the sql Table

Azure Sql Table (Sink)

I am completely at a loss. The only thing which I have found so far which MAY be a culprit is in the output file (which I can also see by inspecting the flow) is that all of the columns which are getting set as NULL are referencing "body" in the externalCall as the source Column whereas shop_id is (which is assigned later in the addShopId Derived Column) is identified explicitly in this lineage and it happens to be the only one being set with a value.
DataFlow SqlSink Column Lineage

ExternalCall
Type

Output

DataPreview

Just to rule out anything with the drifted columns, at one point I added a "Derived Column" activity which mapped the drifted columns and still no success. Even if that would have worked though it goes against the purpose of this flow which is to pass in "Dynamic" sets of mappings and endpoints to be able to parse different sets of data.
Below is a link to the output JSON file here as well.
Azure Dataflow Output file
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Please keep in mind the note above about the purpose of this DataFlow in utilizing the Drifted Schema.
Linked Below is a copy of both the Script Representation and JSON code representation of the data flow.
Script Representation
Dataflow Script Representation
JSON Representation
Dataflow JSON Representation

are you getting any error?

No Errors. The pipeline runs successfully each time. I forgot to attached the JSON output file in my initial response so I just added that if you want to take a look.  Another thing I forgot to mention was that even when I traced the Queries that were running in Azure Sql (IE Insert / Update / Merge) (which also had all the correct mappings and fields) and reproduced them myself with test data they successfully created data in the fields where Azure is placing NULL(s). So that is the only other clue I have so far that I suspect data isn't actually being passed like it is shown in the dataviews

FYI solutions don't belong in your question - they belong as a proper answer.

You may get issue with the flatten transformation, after External Call activity, you can achieve your requirement using below approach:
Click on import projection in output tab of External Call activity, it will import the data of page with type as shown below:

It will import the data as complex object.

Add derived column activity to the External Call activity create columns of Complex data as shown below:

It will create the columns as required, use select activity, select the required columns, use alter activity according to your requirement, Add SQL sink with insert and upsert options, Debug the pipeline, data will insert into the SQL db successfully as shown below:

Here is the dataflow Json for your reference:
{
    "name": "dataflow3",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "externalCall1",
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "RestService1",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AlterRow1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          ID as string,",
                "          DeltaValue as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "derivedColumn1 call(output(",
                "          body as (body as string, id as string, title as string, userId as string)",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     format: 'rest',",
                "     store: 'restservice',",
                "     timeout: 30,",
                "     requestInterval: 0,",
                "     httpMethod: 'GET',",
                "     rowRelativeUrl: 'myid',",
                "     skipRowRelativeUrl: true,",
                "     bodyColumnName: 'body',",
                "     requestFormat: ['type' -> 'json'],",
                "     responseFormat: ['type' -> 'json', 'documentForm' -> 'singleDocument']) ~> externalCall1",
                "source1 derive(myid = toString(ID)) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "select1 alterRow(upsertIf((isNull(myid)==false()))) ~> AlterRow1",
                "externalCall1 derive(id = body.id,",
                "          userId = body.userId,",
                "          title = body.title,",
                "          body = body.body) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 select(mapColumn(",
                "          myid,",
                "          body,",
                "          id = derivedColumn2@id,",
                "          userId,",
                "          title",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "AlterRow1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:true,",
                "     keys:['myid'],",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}


Thank you Bhavani for this suggestion. However, I am trying to stay away from import the projection at any activity since that would effectively void the use case of this DataFlow. I edited my post to add the JSON and Script representation for more context in this regard and so you can see what I am referring to. Where the Flatten Activity is Dynamically Re-Naming columns to convert JSON properties to Sql Columns via a lookup in the cachedMappings Sink. This is so I can use this flow for different relative URI's which will have different objects and properties in the response.
